# Is it possbile to have NPE if variable is initialised with lateinit or synthetic extension?

Tags: android, exception, kotlin, nullpointerexception

Is it possible to have NPE if the variable is initialised with lateinit?

1/ lateinit var pbar: ProgressBar

2/ pbar = findViewById(R.id.pbar_login)

3/ make an api call, pbar.visibility = View.VISIBLE

4/ pressback and destroy the activity(assuming that all views will also get destroyed)

5/

```
override fun onPostExecute() {
    if (pbar != null) { // warning: pbar != null is always true
        pbar.visibility = View.GONE // NPE??
    }
}
```

**Questions:**

1) Is it possible to get NPE if I don't check for -  if (pbar != null) ?

2) Same question if variables are generated through synthetic extension, will there be any NPE?

---

I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33023443/kotlin-lateinit-properties-npe-danger) question, in this case, my further question is,

Are there any best practices to avoid NPE for views related variables in activity, fragments or recyclerview?

Comment: your problem is not `lateinit var`, but activity life cycle. Doing ui job after activity is destroyed is bad. there are a lot of ways to make it work, rxjava, couroutines, livedata, presenter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to get NPE if I don't check for - if (pbar != null) ?

No. That property cannot be `null`.

However, you are likely to crash anyway. Do not attempt to modify a destroyed activity, including updating its views. Either:

- Use something like `LiveData` to tell the activity about the event, so the activity can respond to the event if the activity is around, but the event can be ignored if the activity is destroyed; or
- Check `isDestroyed` on the activity to see if it was destroyed, before attempting to update its views (also consider `isFinishing`, as you may not need to bother with the view updates anyway)

Of the two, I strongly recommend the former approach, as part of replacing `AsyncTask`.

> Same question if variables are generated through synthetic extension, will there be any NPE?

No, it cannot be `null`, but you can crash anyway (see above).

Comment: Thanks for your theoretical answer. However, I am looking for a more precise solution for a typical use case where there is an API call, user press back button and, now, how to prevent NPE? 

For now, we are using https://loopj.com/android-async-http/ with custom subscription based logic in order to prevent NPE. Since we're migrating our code to Kotlin, do you have any recommendation for API call with Retrofit + Coroutines + synthetic extension to prevent NPE?

Comment: @Chitrang: Again, NPE is not your problem, at least not directly. A non-`null` property or variable cannot be `null`. However, if the activity has been destroyed by the time your asynchronous work completes, even though your references to the `View` objects will not be `null`, they may still result in crashes. "do you have any recommendation" -- I covered that in my answer. [This sample app](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-kotlin/tree/v0.4/Weather) illustrates the `LiveData` approach that I mentioned, along with Retrofit and coroutines.